# Error on uninstalling package via apex

Tags: platform-bug, uninstall

I am getting the below error while uninstalling a package using metadata service. This issue is coming sometimes

> Error:- . common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ORA-20011: 10743448001074344800126 ORA-06512: at "DOPEY.CLOCK", line 34 ORA-06512: at "DOPEY.CLOCK", line 217 ORA-06512: at "DOPEY.CLOCK", line 261 ORA-06512: at "DOPEY.CLOCK", line 272 ORA-06512: at line 1 SQLException while executing plsql statement: {call cLock.acquire_lock(?)}(PKG)

Comment: `DOPEY.CLOCK` probably necessitates raising a Case with Salesforce... lol

Comment: There is some info avalible about ORA-06512 @ http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora06512.php

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_20011_approximate_ndv_failed_ora_29913.htm

Comment: Your best bet is is to contact support.

Comment: This is the exception beyond the Salesforce instance. It is exception at platform internal level and not related to any issue in the package. "We don't run plsql statements" :) Contact SFDC support.

Answer (score 36):

The Seven Dwarfs live in the platform code. You should never see DOPEY, SLEEPY, DOC, GRUMPY, SNEEZY, BASHFUL, or HAPPY, but occasionally they break out and appear to a user. If you spot one of them, you need to contact support so they can be put back in their dwarfy walled garden.

Comment: While this might read like a joke it's the best approximation of the truth about dwarves that can be posted publicly.