# "System.AsyncException: could not store job" while scheduling job

Tags: scheduled-apex

We have a business processing where we are scheduling a job(To send welcome SMS) to be run after 2 hours when a high volume opportunity reaches a certain stage.

We are scheduling that job from the trigger. The job is running properly since last few months. Today all of a sudden that job failed with below message in Apex Job Queue

```
    System.AsyncException: could not store job: RunVerificationChecksInScheduler2546161332018 orgId: 00D9E0000001OFL common.exception.SqlDupValOnIndexException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (CORE.AKCRON_JOB_DETAIL) violated
ORA-06512: at "GRUMPY.UDDDMLCRONJOBDETAIL", line 32
ORA-06512: at "GRUMPY.CCRONJOBDETAIL", line 95
ORA-06512: at line 1


{call cCronJobDetail.insert_detail(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}

{call cCronJobDetail.insert_detail(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
16:45:26.90 (3090828642)|FATAL_ERROR|System.AsyncException: could not store job: RunVerificationChecksInScheduler2546161332018 orgId: 00D9E0000001OFL common.exception.SqlDupValOnIndexException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (CORE.AKCRON_JOB_DETAIL) violated
ORA-06512: at "GRUMPY.UDDDMLCRONJOBDETAIL", line 32
ORA-06512: at "GRUMPY.CCRONJOBDETAIL", line 95
ORA-06512: at line 1


{call cCronJobDetail.insert_detail(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}

{call cCronJobDetail.insert_detail(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
```

Am damm sure, it has nothing to do with Scheduler code, can anyone put some light on this. I don't think its GACK, can someone let me know what is its root cause and how can we make sure this does not happen again.

Thanks.

Comment: You found a [dwarf](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41142)!

Comment: You're right, in a sense, it's not a gack. It's even worse than a gack, because a gack implies that the error was properly handled and logged, and you would have gotten an error number. All you can do is contact support so they can log a bug and get this fixed.

Comment: "Worse than a gack" on Tuesday noon is not a great sign. Am having a bad day for sure. 
Thanks for your help. Will raise with SF support.

Comment: I've dropped a message to Chris Peterson, too, but he hasn't responded yet. You might want to drop your scheduled code in here, though, maybe one of us can spot something "unusual" going on. Sometimes we write code that simply works in an unusual way, and then Salesforce fixes that unusual way, and causes existing code to break. It's rare, but not unheard of.

Comment: do we know the solution for this yet? we are getting 20 errors like this for each day.

Comment: @Suneel you have to raise a case with salesforce support

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Thanks for the reply. I did. Earlier, I was invoking Scheduled Job after 1 min. They asked me to increase it to 5 min. I am still getting these errors after increasing it to 5 mins. Thought I could get some solutions here.