# What is this error?

Tags: error

> Error: Invalid Data.  Review all error messages below to correct your
>   data. system.security.NoDataFoundException: ORA-20001: ORA-06512: at
>   "HAPPY.SACCESS", line 833 ORA-01403: no data found ORA-06512: at
>   "HAPPY.CACCESS", line 2869 ORA-06512: at "HAPPY.CACCESS", line 2768
>   ORA-06512: at line 1 SQLException while executing plsql statement:
>   {call cAccess.check_entity_access_proc_ncu(?,?,?,?,?,?)}(EXCLUDED,
>   EXCLUDED, 003F000001m7Yxz, EXCLUDED, true, false)

I am getting this error on one of the sandboxes. Any idea on what these are?

Looks definitely an issue with salesforce and not something we have done.

Comment: Error seems to be mentioned here- [Salesforce, Oracle and the Seven Dwarfs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76423/salesforce-oracle-and-the-seven-dwarfs). You are lucky to find one of the dwarfs :D Look at Mr. sfdcfox's [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/41155/4726)

Comment: The only time I have seen errors like this from Salesforce is in a 'partial' sandbox where the random selection of data can lead to some weird platform errors. So if you get this sort of error in a 'partial' sandbox, first thing to check is whether you get the same error in a regular sandbox