# System.DmlException: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, A workflow or approval field update caused an error when saving this record in Apex

Tags: apex, exception, platform-bug

**Full Error message:**

> System.DmlException: Process failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, A workflow or approval field update caused an error when saving this record.
>
> Contact your administrator to resolve it. common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ORA-20067: ORA-06512: at "DOC.CPICKLIST", line 3388 ORA-01403: no data found ORA-06512: at line 1 SQLException while executing plsql statement: {?=call cPicklist.get_or_make_new_pick_apextest(?,?,?,?)}(EXCLUDED (2), EXCLUDED (25), EXCLUDED (25), EXCLUDED): []
>
> Stack Trace: Class.Order_AutoApprove_Batch_Test.testMethodOne: line 77, column 1

The code I have at 77th line of test class is

```
Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);
```

The same code was working fine in UAT (**SeeAllData is not true**). But it is not working when I am validating the Change Set in Production.

Same error is occurring in all the places that I have this line in test class.

Comment: You need to contact support. See [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/41142).

Comment: @sfdcfox is the 7 dwarves error a gack, or do we need a a new tag?

Comment: @PartOfTheOhana I'd say that this probably falls under the [tag:platform-bug].

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. As suggested, I have raised a case to Salesforce Support. Will post it here for reference as soon as I hear from them.

Comment: Hi All, 
I raised a case to Salesforce Support and heard that they have seen this kind of issues and mostly due to dependency among components. 
As a workaround, they recommended me to do an Incremental Deployment to avoid much dependency between the components. 
Luckily, that worked out to me when I split my single change set into 7 change sets.